# How to remove line from path?

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I have called a **canvas.drawPath()** from onDraw(Canvas canvas) method of View to draw path. It draws a line on path. In my example i am going to draw rectangle on path by using **Path.addRect(RectF, Direction.CCW)**. Its working fine but it draw a rectangle with line. So   shows the line between two rectangle. i just want to remove line from path and draw only the rectangle. Is there any way to remove line from path?

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to create a boolean value called "drawPath". Put all of the logic for drawing the path in an if statement:

```
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
   if(drawPath){
       // path drawing logic goes here
   }
}
```

Then when you want to draw the path, set "drawPath' to true and call View.Invalidate to force the view to redraw. When you want to remove the path, set "drawPath" to false and call View.Invalidate.

Comment: @Jay- It will not help. It is the default behaviour of drawPath() to draw line. I have found solution that set Path.quadTo(mX, mY, mX, mY) as same as you set for rectangle size after the Path.addRec() method.